# PHP upload system on Windows server checklist

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, upload, php.ini, settings

i have an upload system in php, i want it to upload large files, some may get up to 200mb. This means that it will not only take a lot f bandwidth, server memory space but also a lot of time to upload these files.

Now i have a system working, but it seems to fail when trying to upload a large file. I've tested it with a a file that is 22mb and it works like a charm, whoever, when i up this to a file that is about 89.4mb it fails, it goes through the whole upload process but when it tries to post the file it gives me an error.

No i have changed a number of settings in the php.ini file:

- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size
- max_input_time
- max_execution_time
- memory_limit

I then realised that my IIS server has an execution time limit set and that was at about 2 minutes so i made this about 30 (note in testing i the upload of the 80.4mb file was around 23 minutes or so). Error i get is "404 - File or directory not found". This is strange because to doesn't do it for the smaller file.

The only thing i can think of is that there is a setting somewhere in my Windows Server that is stopping my system from moving such a big file from temp files to the correct directory.... Or maybe the temp files cannot handle such a file size?

So, i was wondering if someone could write a check list of the settings that need to be updated in order to upload large files like this because i am almost there, it's just something is stopping me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the [`httpRuntime` attribute called `maxRequestLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx). This value defaults to 4096 KB (4MB)

If you have the Request Filtering feature installed you might also want to look at the [`requestLimits` attribute called `maxAllowedContentLength`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits). This value will default to 30.000.000KB, so if you need to upload files bigger than 28MB, you'll have to increase this value as well

Comment: So i changed both those settings to 120000000 and still getting the 404 error! This is really starting to annoy me now i can't find why i'm getting this. any other settings you can suggest? Also do you know where the server would log the 404 error?